# Which groups $H$ act transitively on a noncompact symmetric space $G/K$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces

All Lie groups here are assumed to be real.
Let $M=G/K$ be a symmetric space of noncompact type and $H \subset G$.
$H$ acts on $G/K$ by left-multiplication.
If $H$ is a parabolic subgroup, then $H$ acts transitively on $M$.

> Question:
>   If $H$ acts transitively on $M$, is $H$ parabolic in $G$?

It is known that any proper subgroup $H \subset G$ is contained in a maximal reductive subgroup of $G$ or a maximal parabolic subgroup of $G$.
All parabolic subgroups of $G$ act transitively on $M$.
Reductive subgroups never act transitively on $M$, so their subgroups also do not act transitively.

That said, can there be a subgroup of a maximal parabolic which is not parabolic itself, but still acts transitively on $G/K$?
I suspect the answer is yes but couldn't come up with an example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is: No. There exist groups acting transitively on $G/K$ that are not parabolic. As an example take a space $G/K$ with
$$\mathfrak{k}_0
:=
\{ X \in \mathfrak{k} : [X,\mathfrak{a}]=0 \}
\neq \{ 0\},$$
for example $G=SO^0_{r,r+n}$, $K=SO_r SO_{r+n}$ with $r \geq 2$, $n \geq 2$.
(This has $\mathfrak{k}_0=\mathfrak{so}_n$ as listed in *Berndt, Console, Olmos: Submanifolds and Holonomy*, p. 339)
Then the minimal parabolic of $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{k}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$ with corresponding Lie group $Q$.
$AN$ acts transitively on $M$ but is not parabolic, as it does not contain a copy of the minimal parabolic.

Moreover:
It seems that all groups acting transitively on $M$ are given as the connected subgroup with Lie algebra $\hat{\mathfrak{k}} \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$ where $\hat{\mathfrak{k}}$ is any subalgebra of $\mathfrak{k}$.
I heard this fact but don't know of a proof.