# If $H$ acts transitively on $G/K$, does it contain a copy of $AN$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces

This is the question that I actually meant to ask in [Which groups $H$ act transitively on a noncompact symmetric space $G/K$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794406/which-groups-h-act-transitively-on-a-noncompact-symmetric-space-g-k) I got confused about the definition of *parabolic subgroups*, so the answer to that question is something that I'm actually not interested in.
What I'm really interested in is the following:

All Lie groups here are assumed to be real.
Let $M=G/K$ be a symmetric space of noncompact type and $H \subset G$.
$H$ acts on $G/K$ by left-multiplication.
Assume that action of $H$ on $M$ is transitive.
Let $G=KAN$ be the Iwasawa decomposition of $G$.

> Question 1:
>   Does $H$ contain a copy of $AN$?

That is:
Is there a subgroup of $H$ isomorphic to $AN$?

> Question 2:
>   Does $H$ contain a subgroup $g AN g^{-1}$, where $g \in G$?

Here is what I've thought so far:

For convenience we write $G=NAK$.
$H$ acting on $M$ transitively means that in particular for all $na \in NAK$ we find $\hat{h} \in H$, $\hat{k} \in K$ such that $\hat{h}=na \hat{k}$.
Let $\hat{h}=n_h a_h k_h$ be the Iwasawa decomposition of $\hat{h}$.
From the uniqueness of this representation follows that $n_h=n$, $a_h=a$, $k_h=\hat{k}$.
Thus, we get an injective map
$$
AN  \rightarrow H \\
an  \mapsto ank_h.
$$
Now, this map need not be continuous, but it suggests that the answer to question 1 will be "yes".